# Show an element with handle

Tags: jquery

I want to show/hide an element with an handle. My dev page is [here](http://dev.lephonographe.fr/) and the handle is the Contact button. Since I can only show/hide an entire element, I've got a fixed Contact button which can be clicked when the contact page is hidden, and one in the contact page itself when it's shown. The problem is that when the contact page is hiding, it overlaps the fixed Contact button.

I've been given the solution shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/F6Efp/8/), but since my element does not start from the top of the screen, with a negative `top` it's visible outside of the container element.

Is there any way to hide the part of the element which is outside its parent? Or is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide elements that flow outside it's parent, you could add `overflow:hidden` to the parent